# How to adjust the brightness of color image?

Tags: opencv

http://yester-place.blogspot.com/2008/11/opencv_12.html

the code is use to adjust the brightness and contrast of gray image.
How can i adjust it with the color image, that is, the result is color image.
thank you

Comment: Google gives the first result - "Changing the contrast and brightness of an image!" tutorial with OpenCV - http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html

Answer (score -1):

You may want to switch from RGB color space to HSV color space. In this case, you would change the brightness of the image by changing the value of the H component of your image and then convert it back.

RGB is not a suitable color space for manipulation.

The function you might want to use is (using python):

```
def RGB2HSV(imgRGB):
    """
    Converts an iplImage in RGB to HSV color scale, same size, same number of channels.
    """
    if imgRGB == None:
            print "imgRGB is void.Exiting . . ."
            return None
    if imgRGB.nChannels < 3:
            print "imgRGB is single channel. Exiting . . ."
            return None

    dims = imageInfo(imgRGB)
    imgHSV = cv.CreateImage( dims, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, imgRGB.nChannels)

    cv.CvtColor(imgRGB, imgHSV, cv.CV_RGB2HSV)

    return imgHSV
```